# Moving Files to Offline Machines

Tags: powershell

I have created the below script to send files to specific users within the business, this script works without any issues.

```
$a = Get-Content "C:\Powershell\srvlist.txt" 
foreach ($i in $a) {
    $files = get-content "C:\Powershell\filelist.txt"
    foreach ($file in $files) {
        Copy-Item $file -Destination \\$i\Apps -force
    }
}
```

The destinations for the computers to be sent too are included in the `srvlist.txt`:

```
unit123\c$\users\jamesfegan\
unit124\c$\users\timhobon\
```

and the file to be transferred are stored within the `filelist.txt`:

```
C:\Powershell\testfile.exe
```

However some users work offline and will only show on our network once they connect to the VPN, so we want to ensure that if the computer is unreachable the file will be present as soon as that machine next comes online.

If `unit124` is showing as offline and is off site, is there a way to cache this command so the file can be sent as soon it next connects to the network?

Comment: Invert the control. Make the clients to pull stuff from server instead of pushing to the clients.

Comment: Scheduled Task?

Comment: I was thinking Scheduled task however the admins are wanting to select when the script runs to ensure the files that are being sent are in fully working order. This also runs into the same problem if the users aren't on site.

Comment: Looks like a good case for using Group Policy preference to copy files. The files will copy when group policy updates and can be targeted to specific users or computers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I am aware there is no way to "cashe" a command, however, you can use a "while" command to continuously loop all of the computers that it has not successfully moved all of the files to.

Try this.

```
$SvrsTarget    = Get-Content "C:\Powershell\srvlist.txt"
$SvrsFiles     = get-content "C:\Powershell\filelist.txt"
$SvrsCompleted = 0
While ($SvrsTarget.Count -NE 0) {
    foreach ($Server in $SvrsTarget) {
        $SvrsError = $False
        foreach ($file in $files) {
            Try {
                Copy-Item $file -Destination \\$Server\Apps -force
            } Catch {$SvrsError = $True}
        }
        IF ($SvrsError -EQ $False) {$SvrsTarget.Remove($Server)}
    }
}
```

But as others have said, there are better ways of accomplishing this goal. Its almost always better to have the users pull the files than trying to push files out.

- You can use a group policy to run a startup script so when the computer logs on to run a powershell script and write to a log file on a shared drive you can review later on.
- Scheduled task can run RoboCopy to download the files as soon as there is network connectivity to the share drive by manipulating the retry attempts & wait between attempts.

Comment: I've had further talks with the team and it turns out they want to implement a bash script through openVPN so when the users connect to the network it will locate the file and look at the date that file was last updated/uploaded. If it is newer than the file on the local machine it will copy the file over.